# Metro style app with DirectX portion

Tags: c++, xaml, directx, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Will the Windows 8 APIs allow me to write an app that uses XAML for the UI and DirectX for rendering 3D objects? Say I am writing a 3D modeling app. There are a lot of dialogs and UI elements that I would like to make in XAML, and a single rectangular window that I would render with DirectX. I prefer using C++. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good news! It seems that the release version of Windows 8 will allow Metro/XAML and DirectX Interop!

> This is a common theme that we heard after we released the Developer Preview. Developers like you wanted to combine the high-performance immediate-mode rendering capabilities of DirectX with the rich interactivity, control model, and design-time experience of XAML.
>
> We heard you. With the Consumer Preview, you can now smoothly integrate XAML and DirectX 11 in the same Metro style app to create a fast and fluid experience. For example, you can now create a DirectX game and use XAML to process input, create graphics for heads-up displays and menus, or bind to your app’s data model.
>
> To this end, we added 3 new XAML types to support a broad range of DirectX interop scenarios, each with different capabilities:
>
> - SurfaceImageSource enables full composition of DirectX content into a    XAML app. This allows drawing DirectX content into the XAML
>   visual    tree, useful for complex image effects, data visualization,
>   and other    immediate-mode drawing scenarios.
> - VirtualSurfaceImageSource is used for large-scale virtualized    content. This is targeted toward apps that require panning and
>   zooming of large content, like maps and document viewers.
> - SwapChainBackgroundPanel targets full-screen, DirectX-focused    scenarios. This is great for games and other low-latency, full-screen
>   DirectX apps with a XAML overlay.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/3/01/what-s-changed-since-build-part-1.aspx)

Take a look at [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) for more detail.

Depending on how well (or badly) this turns out, you still have the option of abandoning Metro for WPF, because WPF and Direct3D can interop.

Comment: so there is a light in a tunnel. If I choose WPF instead of Metro, will I be able to sell app in Windows 8 App Store?